What is the recommended approach for scalable caching in retrofit?
Retrofit allows caching responses for particular requests by passing file path where it will store the results.
We ran scale test on these numbers and in our JFR we are seeing major time now going to DiskFileCache reads which makes sense as it depends where the file reads are coming from.
Persistent disks vs SSD etc.
Wanted to know what is the general practice for scaling to have generic caching in retrofit on client side so we can save both http calls and high throughput.
Currently trying adding in memory cache in network interceptor.
Setup, we are using retrofit2.6 in our java applications
We ran scale test on these numbers and in our JFR we are seeing major time now going to DiskFileCache reads which makes sense as it depends where the file reads are coming from.
Persistent disks vs SSD etc.
Wanted to know what is the general practice for scaling to have generic caching in retrofit on client side so we can save both http calls and high throughput.
Currently trying adding in memory cache in network interceptor.
